# Post an order to Shopify for unknown user

Tags: api, shopify

Is there a way to post an order, including payment information and shipping information, to Shopify for a new user?

For example, user ABC wants to purchase a product through my website (that is not a shopify website), and I gather all of the information required to make the purchase, including shipping address, credit card, etc. User ABC is not known to Spotify. Is there a way for me to use the Shopify API to process this transaction, including payment processing and everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a sales channel called **Buy Button**. You can use that for your purpose.

1. [Buy Button](https://www.shopify.in/buy-button)
2. [Creating a Buy Botton](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/buy-button/create-buy-button)
3. [Adding a Buy Button](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/buy-button)